# Class Loading: Compile time or Runtime

Tags: java, runtime

Is java class loaded at compile time or Runtime? I know you can dynamically load a java class using your own Class Loaders or calling `Class.forName("fully qualified name of java file")`.

But if I am not using any of the above techniques then does it means that Java classes are loaded at compile time?

Comment: Obviously runtime. What good would they do at compile time?

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-dyn0429/ detailed info on class loading if youre interested

Comment: Yeah.. I agree I was astonished when someone asked me a question: what is the difference between compile time and run time class loading

Answer (score 2):

No. The [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.2) explains how loading and linking is runtime. Any binary-compatible revision of a class can be thrown in place of an existing class.

A class is compiled with a symbolic reference to other classes, not the code of those classes.

However with certain non-JVM compilers like GCJ classes can be compiled ahead of time into one executable.

Answer (score 1):

Classes are loaded at runtime to execute their code.

Classes are loaded at compile time to check code using the class for type safety.
Whenever you write code that uses a class (eg, calling a method on it), the compiler needs to load that class to make sense of your code (eg, to check methods or base type)

Comment: Hi hexafraction/Jack, as per SLacks class loading also takes place at compile time. But I think at compile time in class file only references of the dependents are kept and class is actually loaded at run time when it is required.

Comment: @user1841293: What do you mean?

Comment: Hi SLaks,As per your comment class loading takes place at compile time also for type safety and at runtime class is loaded to execute the code. Correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: Hi SLaks,I have one more doubt.Suppose if there is a class A containing a static block. Now if I write A a = null, the static block wont be executed but if I write A a = new A() then the static block is executed i.e. class is loaded. Does it means that class loading takes place at run time.

Comment: @user1841293: Your question is unclear / meaningless.  If you load the class at runtime, it is loaded at runtime.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33922/discussion-between-user1841293-and-slaks)

Answer (score 0):

At compile time nothing is loaded. At compile time classes are just generated from sources.

The difference could be if a class is loaded by the `ClassLoader` when the JVM powers up or if you do it dynamically during the execution, but they are two sides of the same medal.

In both cases they are loaded dynamically, but in the former this is done as soon as the JVM starts.

Comment: as SLaks noted, Classes are loaded at compile time to check code using the class for type safety. For example, if you implement java.lang.Runnable, compiler requires that public void run() were overwriten, and compiler knows that after looking into class Runnable.

Comment: @Alexei KaigorodovBut suppose if there is a class A containing a static block. Now if I write A a = null, the static block wont be executed but if I write A a = new A() then the static block is executed i.e. class is loaded. Does it means that class loading takes place at run time. If you are accessing compile-time constants then in that case class wont get loaded at all.

Comment: I argued against the phrase "At compile time nothing is loaded". Of course, JVM loads classes at runtime, no one denies that.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov: at compile time nothing can be loaded just because there is no JVM. The fact that the type checker must check the signature of the classes doesn't have anything to do with the concept of class loading itself, it could just read the interface without bothering about anything else, they are not the same thing at all.

Comment: This is purely terminological issue. By loading, I mean reading and parsing the class file. The JVM spec itself uses "loading" in 2 senses: full loading, made by Classloader.loadClass(), and reading and parsing (the first stage of full loading, others are Linking and Initializing, see chapter 5). The reading and parsing by compiler and by jvm are closely related (they must comply with each other), and can be done with the same program library.

Answer (score 0):

As many others have stated, classes are loaded at runtime unless you are using an AOT compiler to allow them to run in non-JVM environments. If you want to read up all the details on how the Java Virtual Machine starts up, initializes and loads the first then subsequent classes you can take a look at the [Java SE 7 specifications](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1).